# azure-java-sdk: Azure Java SDK installation without Maven

Tags: maven, azure-java-sdk

Due to my company's network policies, I am unable to use Maven to install Azure Java SDK.
Is there any way at all to install Azure Java SDK without Maven?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gradle to install all dependencies you need . Details [see here](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-applications/)

If you want to install [azure-java-sdk](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure/1.3.0) , you can find how to install it using Gradle under Gradle tag :
[image]

copy it to here in your Gradle  project:

[image]

refresh it and it will start download dependencies to your project :
[image]

Hope it helps !

Comment: Super :) that did the trick. This worked much better than Maven. I just had to re-build my project with 'gradlew build' and update my proxy settings ('gradle.properties' file). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @Namta , Glad to know that my suggestion is helpful for you. Pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark it as an answer so that it will help others who has similar issue and it will be an award for me. Thanks and have a nice day !